# react & axios & PHP [Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.]

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

**client**

```
import axios from "axios"; 

export const logIn = (id, email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const config={
            method:'post',
            url:'http://localhost/cup/cup.php',
            headers:{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            },
            data:{
                id:id,
                email:email,
                password:password
            }
        };

        axios.request(config).then((res) => {
            // console.log(res.data);
        });
```

**server[=cup.php]**

```
<?php
include ("./conn.php");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

> when I send a post request, the error above will show me.

[image: console message]

[image: XHR message]

I don't know what's the problem?

I looked for the answer on Stack Overflow. I tried but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Is there an error in PHP error log file? Did you try this API call from Postman?

Comment: I tried to find an error from my error log file, but no error. Also, I used API Tester to  try my API, it responsed okay

Comment: Thanks, dude. I got an idea form you Now I solve my problem. I am really appreciated to you @ VnoitKumar

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: The issue is that Axios headers. I change 'headers'  to 'header'. I don't know why but it does work. But I search Axios doc there are no code styles like me. So do you know why?@ VnoitKumar

Comment: maybe I delete headers code, that would be better

Comment: _“I don't know why but it does work”_ - it works now, because now you stopped sending a header, that made zero sense in the first place. (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header.) _“But I search Axios doc there are no code styles like me”_ - of course there aren’t, because headers are passed under the key `headers`. By making that `header`, you just passed an arbitrary option name, that Axios does not recognize - therefor your completely bogus header does not get send any more. Of course instead of `header`, you might as well have used `hussigussigoo`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header. Thanks for your comment @ CBroe

Answer (score 1):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response to your request from the API. The 3rd party API you call defines under what condition it allows CORS.